# How do I add pages to a yo web app without breaking my grunt scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, gruntjs, bower

I have been using  yo / bower for a few weeks now and I am enjoying it quite a bit.  However I am having troubles adding additional pages to my web app (that require JS).

I am currently configuring the grunt `index.html` to minimize my custom JS files into a single file.  This works file as long as I put them into `main.js`, but now I would like to break up the scripts into separate files based on the html file.  Below are the `build:js` sections I'm trying to use to accomplish this.

As of now it generates `page1.js` and `page2.js` but sadly doesn't run.  On document load I get this error.

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Is this the correct way to add additional html files to the yo web app?  Nearly all of the examples I have found regarding grunt / yo only discuss `index.html`.

**index.html**

```
<!-- build:js scripts/page1.js -->
<script src="scripts/page1_specific_scrip_1.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/page1_specific_scrip_2.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js scripts/page2.js -->
<script src="scripts/page2_specific_scrip_1.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/page2_specific_scrip_2.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

**page1.html**

```
<!-- build:js scripts/page1.js -->
<script src="scripts/page1_specific_scrip_1.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/page1_specific_scrip_2.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

**page2.html**

```
<!-- build:js scripts/page2.js -->
<script src="scripts/page2_specific_scrip_1.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/page2_specific_scrip_2.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured a few things out... Below are the changes I have made to get things working.

**Build Changes**
I now only include the files to be built in `index.html`.  Meaning inside pageX.html I only have:

```
<!-- build:js scripts/pageX.js -->
<!-- endbuild -->`
```

**`Unexpected token '<'`**

This error was not caused by anything do to with grunt / yo.  My Django's url mapping was responding to the request for `diag.js` unexpectedly.  Rather than serving the javascript it was serving the view for `diag`.  I noticed when viewing the source for the served .js file it was in fact the full HTML file. Lesson learned **do not name your javascript files the same as a view**.